# How do I use convert two separate EF contexts to one with Linked Servers?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have inherited a project where we have two different Entity Framework 6 contexts pointing to two different databases.  The databases share some related records, but to query the two we have to so something like this:

```
            using (var ctx1 = new MainContext())
            {
                using (var ctx2 = new SecondaryContext())
                {
                    var personIds = (from oc in ctx2.OrderContacts
                                     join o in ctx2.Orders on oc.OrderId equals o.OrderId
                                     where o.Order_rowID == orderId
                                     select oc.PersonId).Distinct();

                    if (personIds.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (var personId in personIds)
                        {
                            Contact contact = ctx1.ContactSet.Where(x => x.ExternalId == personId).SingleOrDefault();
                            if (contact == null)
                            {
                                // Do something to create a record
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
```

In the above case, the Contact Table in the Main Context stores an ExternalId which is a GUID in the Secondary Context's Person table.

I have a linked server set up between the two databases, so I would like to be able to do all my joins in the Main Context without having to open a second connection from the server.   Both contexts were originally created as Code First EF solutions (in different apps).

Comment: If you are going to query both databases, you shouldn't be executing a query for every row in the first query, rather execute one query (per database) that gets all of the appropriate rows that you need.

Comment: Oh I know.  This is just one sample of the code I am having to deal with that I inherited.  I would typically get all the ids from the first, query the second with an "in clause" and then join them locally.  I am hoping I can offload some to the SQL server and let it do the joins across the linked servers though.  This isn't meant to be a GOOD example of what it does, just a simple one to get the question across.

Comment: just as an idea - what about `View` on SQL side that will use linked server\DB, and then add that view to your EF Context

Comment: How would I add that view to my EF Context?  The context was built as Code First and we have added new tables in code as we go.  Do i use migrations to get the view seen as an entity in the context, or do I have to code it manually?